# Sorting query output by Month name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, oledb, blueprism

I am trying to extract values from Excel using an SQL Query, but what I've been struggling with is sorting the months in their respective order. Right now the table is being sorted A-Z, I tried playing around with `DATEPART`, but was not very successful as I was getting an Int16 error.

```
Select F1,
SUM(F2),
ROUND(SUM(REPLACE(F3, ',', '.')), 2),
ROUND(SUM(REPLACE(F4, ',', '.')), 2)
FROM [Sheet1$]
WHERE F1 IN ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')
GROUP BY F1;
```

This is the query that works, but the result is:

[image: Result Table]

I am also open to any suggestions that could improve my query speed as the document is quite big, about 50k rows, thanks.

For anyone wondering the final query that worked was:

```
Select F1,
SUM(F2),
ROUND(SUM(REPLACE(F3, ',', '.')), 2),
ROUND(SUM(REPLACE(F4, ',', '.')), 2)
FROM [Sheet1$]
WHERE F1 IN ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')
GROUP BY F1
ORDER BY SWITCH(
F1='January', 1,
F1='February', 2,
F1='March', 3,
F1='April', 4,
F1='May', 5,
F1='June', 6,
F1='July', 7,
F1='August', 8,
F1='September', 9,
F1='October', 10,
F1='November', 11,
F1='December', 12
);
```

Comment: If you want performance advice please post an execution plan.

Comment: Instead of Switch(), consider: `ORDER BY Month([F1] & " 1, 2000")`

Comment: Or `ORDER BY DatePart("m", F1 & " 1 2000")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a `CASE` expression:

```
Select
  f1,
  SUM(f2),
  ROUND(SUM(REPLACE(f3, ',', '.')), 2),
  ROUND(SUM(REPLACE(f4, ',', '.')), 2)
FROM [Sheet1$]
WHERE F1 IN ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
             'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')
GROUP BY F1
ORDER BY
  CASE F1
    WHEN 'January' THEN 1
    WHEN 'February' THEN 2
    WHEN 'March' THEN 3
    WHEN 'April' THEN 4
    WHEN 'May' THEN 5
    WHEN 'June' THEN 6
    WHEN 'July' THEN 7
    WHEN 'August' THEN 8
    WHEN 'September' THEN 9
    WHEN 'October' THEN 10
    WHEN 'November' THEN 111
    WHEN 'December' THEN 12
  END;
```

Or create a month table on the fly:

```
Select
  s.f1,
  SUM(s.f2),
  ROUND(SUM(REPLACE(s.f3, ',', '.')), 2),
  ROUND(SUM(REPLACE(s.f4, ',', '.')), 2)
FROM [Sheet1$] s
JOIN VALUES
(
  ('January', 1),
  ('February', 2),
  ('March', 3),
  ('April', 4),
  ('May', 5),
  ('June', 6),
  ('July', 7),
  ('August', 8),
  ('September', 9),
  ('October', 10),
  ('November', 11),
  ('December', 12)
) months(month_name, month_number) ON s.f1 = months.month_name
GROUP BY s.f1
ORDER BY months.month_number;
```

Or create a real month table.

Comment: After trying to use the first suggestion I started getting the error "Unrecognized keyword WHEN", so I did some digging around and figured out I needed to use SWITCH instead. If that's the case I guess I am using MS Access SQL and not SQL Server, but thanks anyways.

Comment: Ah, okay. MS Access is very different from standard SQL. Hence many SQL sources on the Internet don't work for it and my queries don't either. SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and many other DBMS are much more standard-compliant. I'm glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
order by datepart(mm, f1 + ' 1 2000')
```

Comment: It's `mm` or `Month`. Not `'mm'`. As it is it'll throw _"Invalid parameter 1 specified for datepart."_

Comment: With the suggestion made by GMB I receive a (Invalid procedure call) error, using the suggestion provided by Sami I receive a (No values given for one or more required parameters)

I am using OLE DB driver to run this query if that helps at all.

Comment: @GMB As I mentioned before, I get an error saying I am missing one or more required parameters.

`GROUP BY F1`
`order by datepart(mm, f1 + ' 1 2000');`

Comment: This method relies on this date format (e.g. 'February 1 2000') being recognized by SQL Server. I don't consider this guaranteed.